# Javascript JQuery Property Scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I am reading *Javascript for Kids* by Nick Morgan as a beginner, and I produced the following JavaScript code -

```
var Car = function(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}

Car.prototype.draw = function () {
    var carHtml = '<img src="http://nostarch.com/images/car.png">';
    this.carElement = $(carHtml);

    this.carElement.css({
        position:"absolute",
        left:this.x,
        top:this.y
    });
}

var tesla = new Car (20,20);
var nissan = new Car (100,200);

tesla.draw();
nissan.draw();
```

Now, I used the JavaScript constructor method to create objects and `prototypes` technique to create the draw method, which I can call on the car objects I have created from each instance of `car`.

From my experience in Python, all methods can access all the properties of an object created from an instance of a class.

My question is, are properties accessible by all methods in an object created by the car constructor?

Comment: __Yes__, they are.

Comment: Note that your `Car` constructor doesn't create any methods at all. The code adding `draw` to `Car.prototype` creates the only "method" (this is "method" in the loose sense; as of ES2015, JavaScript got a stricter form of methods).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, are properties accessible by all methods in an object created by the car constructor?

They're accessible to any code that has access to the object. So if a method created by the `Car` constructor (or anything else) has access to the object, then yes, the properties will be accessible to it. If the method created by the `Car` constructor doesn't (e.g., it's creating a method on a different object entirely), then that method may not have access to the properties.

Note that whether the method has access to the object may vary depending on how it's called, if it's accessing the object via `this`. More: [*How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

JavaScript has **no** truly private properties, yet. If you can access the object, you can access all of its true properties.

There is a [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields), currently at Stage 3*, to add private fields to JavaScript objects created via `class` syntax. (It used to be a separate private properties proposal, but it was combined with that class fields proposal.) Private data has had a long an tortured path to date, and while the proposal has reached Stage 3, it still has a fair bit of road to travel.

---

* [Explanation of stages](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/)

Answer (score 1):

Properties like what you defined are a public properties (no such a thing protected in js) and as such are accessible from any other scope having the instance of the object , the real private properties (created with "var" keyword) are only accessible within their closure (meaning: their defined function block or nested blocks).